# Is there a way of finding out which file a form came from?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lets say that I have the following in a file called `example.lisp`.

```
(in-package :example)

(defparameter *global* 'bar)

(defun foo (a b) (list a b))
```

Is there a function that will do something like

```
> (hypothetical-function #'foo)
#P"example.lisp"

> (hypothetical-function '*global*)
#P"example.lisp"
```

I'm specifically looking for a function or macro, not a SLIME command or similar. Bits of the program need to know where other bits came from for the purposes of generating some documentation in generated files, and this seems like the sort of thing that I should be able to do without manually passing in an origin file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an implementation-independent way to do that take a look at `swank::find-source-location`

Comment: Hm. Yup; there are `swank-backend::find-source-location` and `swank:find-definition-for-thing`, both of which seem to return the same result.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this functionality is not part of the standard, but specific implementations may provide it.

For example, in [CCL](http://www.clozure.com/clozurecl.html) (See also `ccl:*record-source-file*`):

```
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.8-dev-r14962-trunk  (WindowsX8632)!
? (load "~/foo/foo.lisp")
#P"C:/Users/dhl/foo/foo.lisp"
? (ccl:find-definition-sources '*foo*)
(((#<VARIABLE-DEFINITION-TYPE VARIABLE #xC157526> . *FOO*) #<SOURCE-NOTE "home:f
oo;foo.lisp":0-22 "(defparameter *foo* 1)">))
? (ccl:source-note-filename (cadar (ccl:find-definition-sources '*foo*)))
"home:foo;foo.lisp.newest"
? (ccl:source-note-filename (ccl:function-source-note #'foo))
"home:foo;foo.lisp.newest"
```

(This uses [logical pathnames](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/19_c.htm).)

So, you would have to read up on your implementation's documentation, or check if there is something like a trivial-find-source library.

Comment: I'll have to check further docs, but it seems like there is also a `sb-introspect:find-definition-source` that might do the equivalent in SBCL. Thanks!